# Omxplayer doesn't play mp4 video

Tags: omxplayer

I have Raspberry Pi version B.

My steps:

1. apt-get update
2. apt-get upgrade
3. apt-get install omxplayer

Then input: **omxplayer video.mp4** but nothing happens....omxplayer only  write to console this information: *File parameters. omx-h264 , 1280x720 profile 100 fps 25*

arm memory=256M gpu memory=256M

I analyzed log file that omxplayer was created but i didn't see nothing strange. How I can find the source of problem ???

PS. This video file play successfully on the my notebook with Win8

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATED**

I invoked

*omxplayer -i video.mp4* and output is:

```
file : 1.mp4 reult 3 format mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 audio streams 1 video streams 1 chapters 0 subtitles 0
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf54.59.106
  Duration: 02:04:21.21, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1932 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1280x720 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1799 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0.1(und): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 127 kb/s

have a nice day ;)
```

This is information about installed codecs

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# vcgencmd codec_enabled H264
H264=enabled
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# vcgencmd codec_enabled MPG2
MPG2=disabled
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# vcgencmd codec_enabled WVC1
WVC1=disabled
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# vcgencmd codec_enabled MPG4
MPG4=enabled
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# vcgencmd codec_enabled MJPG
MJPG=enabled
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# vcgencmd codec_enabled WMV9
WMV9=disabled
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include results of `omxplayer -i video.mp4`? What are you using to play on Win8?

Comment: @dbmitch Many thanks to your answer. I will put results tommorow. I use Windows Media Player to play mp4 video.

Comment: @dbmitch I have updated first post. `Please see it` .

Answer (score 1):

I answer myself. I have upgraded OS on the Rpi to Jessie and all begin to work correctly.